# Is there a way for Watchman to only process "closed/completed" files?

Tags: windows, watchman

I'm using Node.js to start Watchman on Windows 2016 with a number of file type filters on a specific directory.  This directory is being used for staging.  Uploaded files will be routed to other folders depending on the filename.

The problem that I'm having is Watchman is picking up files that are being uploaded.  It causes the moving processes to fail as it's locked.  I'm thinking about using this package to check the file status (@ronomon/opened) before marking it as a candidate for moving.  Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this issue that sounds almost identical to your question; it has some other alternatives and details beyond what I've put below: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/562#issuecomment-355450096

Summarizing that issue here: you need to allow for the filesystem to settle.  There is a `settle` option you can set in your `.watchmanconfig` to control this:

`{"settle": 60000}`

You'd place that file in the upload directory (and make sure that you don't mistake it for an uploaded file and move it out) and then re-create your watch.